# Can select statement be used with tput

Tags: bash

I want to make a menu in the center of the screen with select statement:

```
            tput cup $((height / 2)) $(((width / 2) - (length / 2)))
            echo ${warn_msg}
            tput cup $((height / 2 + 1)) $(((width / 2) - (length / 2)))
            select yn in "Accept" "Quit"
            do
```

the problem is the choices of the menu are not aligned perfectly: only first choice of the select statement is centered.

```
                  Disclaimer: This is a personal script. The author is not responsible for damage of any kind arising from its use.
                  1) Accept
2) Quit
Enter choice:
```

Does anyone know the trick to align the choices nicely?

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Maybe look at a dedicated menu program if you want fancy menus.

Comment: I agree. I guess I have to drop the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select yn in Accept Quit
do COMMANDS
done) |& sed -e "s/^/$(printf %$(( $(tput cols)/2-3 ))s ' ' )/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you like this (choice number returned in `$REPLY`):

```
read < <(dialog 2>&1 >/dev/tty --nocancel --ok-label 'Enter choice' --menu \
'Disclaimer: This is a personal script.
The author is not responsible for damage of any kind arising from its use.' \
0 0 2  1 Accept  2 Quit)
echo You chose $REPLY.
```

or this (choice returned in `$?`):

```
dialog --yes-label Accept --no-label Quit --yesno \
'Disclaimer: This is a personal script.
The author is not responsible for damage of any kind arising from its use.' 0 0
echo You chose $(($?+1)).
```